# Replace a string with json

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, I have a column of type character varying with the content `"London"`.

I want to replace its content with json

```
{
  "en": "London",
  "fr": "Londres"
}
```

Is it possible to do this using SQL commands?

Comment: you can convert json to string and save it.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
SELECT
json_build_object(
   'col', json_agg(col)
   )
FROM mytable
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d25c9db5edd104c4055e7b7d5cfd41c8)

Comment: This is not exactly what I need

Comment: In my table there are no columns "en" and "fr"

Comment: I edited the code. Please enter your desired input and output data.

Answer (score 0):

It worked

```
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN data TYPE json USING CONCAT('{"en":"', data, '", "fr": ""}')::json;


UPDATE table
SET data = data::jsonb || '{"fr":"Londres"}'
WHERE data->>'en' LIKE 'London';

UPDATE table
SET data = data::jsonb || '{"fr":"Moscou"}'
WHERE data->>'en' LIKE 'Moscow';

...
```

Comment: You should define the column as `jsonb` not `json`. And typically using `jsonb_build_object()` is more robust than concatenating values, e.g. `using jsonb_build_object('en', data)`

Answer (score 0):

With the following aproach, the column type needs to stay type character varying. (I believe you are desiring that)

```
--make the current value as JSON value on the "en" key
update "MyTable"  set "data"=  '{"en":'||"data"||'}'

-- add "fr" key and value 
UPDATE "MyTable" SET "data" = jsonb_set("data"::jsonb, '{fr}','"Londres"', TRUE)
WHERE "data"::jsonb->>'en'='London'


--get en value
select "data"::jsonb->'en' from "MyTable"
```